# Which java socket threw the Connection reset IOException?

Tags: java, sockets, server, client, ioexception

I am trying a client-server application in Java.
One of the threads in Server is responsible for listening and accepting connections from multiple clients.
For every connection accepted, this thread keeps appending the new client socket object into a socket-list that it maintains.
Suppose after a while the Server is connected to 10 clients.
Now if the 4th client closes the connection an IOException will be thrown with "Connection reset" message.

Is there a way for the Server to find out which of the sockets, out of the 10, threw this exception?  (in this case the 4th socket)

I don't want to create separate thread for each connection.

Is my approach wrong? 
Appreciate any help.

Comment: The socket that threw the exception is the one you were operating on when the exception was thrown. I don't understand the problem. But if a client closes a connection you should get EOS when reading. You'll only get a 'connection reset' in that case if you're violating your own application protocol by writing data to a connection that has already been closed by the peer.

Comment: You are right.
An IOException will be thrown only when I operate on the socket.
My understanding was wrong.
Also, your answer to question: 10240694 helped. Mine was the 4th case of your answer. Thanks.